# PHP - do JSON files get cached?

Tags: php, json, caching

I built a PHP site powered by local JSON files whose data changes every few weeks. My clients complain they have to clear their browser cache after I update data in the JSON file and this made me wonder if JSON files get cached like images and other files by the client browser?

I load the files into PHP vars like this:

```
$jsonFile = file_get_contents(ROOT . "/data/venues.json");
$venues   = json_decode($jsonFile, true);

// do stuff with $venues
```

Do I need to tell my clients they are imagining things or do I have to add a timestamp query to the json file, e.g.

```
$jsonFile = file_get_contents(ROOT . "/data/venues.json?version=" . filemtime(ROOT . '/data/venues.json'));
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: It's your PHP page that they are accessing.  You need to set cache-control headers.

Comment: If the JSON file is being read and used by PHP on the server then it won't (can't!) be cached by the user's browser. The resulting pages might be cached, though, either by the browser or by some intervening proxy, or both.

Comment: I presume caching isn't involved in this. Do you lock files when they are overwritten? This might be a case of simultaneous access. Is there a possibility to shift to databases and use transactions to achieve [`ACID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties

Comment: @nice_dev I'm not locking files. Database is not an option for this site. The site has several pages containing lots of images which seldom change and I don't mind being cached. The text in those pages does change (stored in JSON files on server). Would adding `header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');` to the data.php file (that loads JSON into $vars) do the trick?

Comment: Why exactly would a database not be an option?

Comment: If the clients are fetching the page with `GET`, the browser will definitely cache it unless you send cache control headers that prevent it. It doesn't matter how the PHP generates the results.

Comment: @KirkRoss Since the text being a small piece of the UI can change and rest would remain the same, caching is indeed the culprit. Yes, setting a cache control would work just fine but as an alternative, you can also load the page with a version get parameter attached with filemtime() like you showed in the code for instant fresh data on the browser.

Comment: @ADyson corporate politics.

Comment: IMO the `version` witht he `filemtime` timestamp is the perfect solution for this.

Comment: @nice_dev when I add a filemtime to the get_file_contents() I get a `can't open stream` error, as if the file doesn't exist. How do I get around that?

Comment: @cottton when I add the filemtime string to the `file_get_contents` I get a `can't open stream` error.

Comment: @KirkRoss My bad, what is the frontend url? You need to add the version key there when you load it.

Comment: @nice_dev It's a backend file, so I think the cache-control header will probably work.

Comment: @KirkRoss Yup, I was actually proposing the frontend way since it would reflect instantly

Answer (score 0):

The answer to `when I add the filemtime string to the file_get_contents I get a can't open stream error.`

is because you added the version to the file **to load**.

But you want to load the actual file (no `?version=...`)

and **then** add the version to the file name to return it to the browser.

Example:

```
// The file (in your example you should add ofc your file and your ROOT constant).
$file = 'tmp/_test.html';
// Get the file modified time (timestamp).
$version = filemtime($file);
// Create the file to return to the browser including the version.
$fileWithVersion = "{$file}?version={$version}";
// Read the content
$content = file_get_contents($file);
// Json decode the content.
$venues   = json_decode($content, true);
// Do what you got to do ...
// ...
```

So `$fileWithVersion` is the filename you would return to the browser:

```
echo $fileWithVersion . PHP_EOL;
// 'tmp/_test.html?version=1635424906'
```